# Generic class to store incoming json list using JsonConverter

Tags: c#, xamarin, json.net, realm, json-deserialization

I am trying to create a generic class that can store response of incoming json of any type to avoid unboxing i am restricting that `T` has to be derived from `RealmObject`

```
public class Response<T>  where T : RealmObject
{
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string totalPages {get;set;}

    public IList<T> responseBody { get; set; }
}
```

Here, `responseBody` parameter is capable of storing list of Contacts,customer or order data fetch from webservice. in order to achieve that i tried to 
extend `JsonConverter` to have control over deserializing process.

Json received from server is as follows (for contact type data)

```
{
  "errorMessage": "",
  "status": "Ok",
  "totalPages": 1,
  "contactsList": [
    {
      "firstName": "Ronald",
      "lastName": "Brownn"
    },
    {

      "firstName": "Elvis",
      "lastName": "Presley"
    }
  ]
}
```

Following is my `Contact` model

```
[JsonCustomAttribute("contactsList")]

public class Contact : RealmObject
{

    public string firstName {get;set;}

    public string lastName { get; set; }        

}
```

so far i am trying to use `JsonConverter` to deserialize the incoming json. Here you can see i have to explicity find the `contactsList` property and then need to create `Response` object with the generic type `Contact` to add all `Contact` data to
`responseBody`. so there any way to make these thing generlize , i mean to find the `contactList` or `customerList` or `orderList` dynamically and create `Response<Contact>` or `Response<Customer>` etc dynamically.

```
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) 
    {

        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        //For contact only
        JArray jArray = jObject.Property("contactsList").Value as JArray;
        Response<Contact> response = new Response<Contact>();
        response.responseBody = jArray.ToObject<IList<Contact>>();        

        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), response);
        return response;


    }
```

Comment: Well as I have mentioned it&#39;s not just about contact , in future there will be other entities as well like customer , orders etc. I am looking for generalize solution

Comment: Ok I think I get what you were trying to do now. Simplify things by having a general property name like `Data` or something

Comment: Yeah I misunderstood/misinterpreted the original issue.

Comment: Are you in control of the data being returned from server?

Comment: nope, i don't have any control

Comment: make the attribute generic and use naming convention

Comment: anymore pointers plz so that i can figure out what you are trying to propose :)

Comment: Testing it out first before I confirm it is a solution.

Comment: Figured out the logic for the converter but having an issue with how to apply it as an attribute

Comment: You are too close now

Answer (score 2):

I originally tried toying around with using it as a generic attribute but had too many issues.

Here is the converter using a naming convention based on the provided type

```
public class ResponseConverter<T> : JsonConverter<Response<T>> where T : RealmObject {

    public override Response<T> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Response<T> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        var typeName = typeof(T).Name;
        var propertyName = string.Format("{0}List", typeName);

        var response = new Response<T>();

        if (jObject.ContainsKey(propertyName) && jObject[propertyName].Type == JTokenType.Array) {
            response.responseBody = jObject.Property(propertyName).ToObject<IList<T>>();
        } else {
            response.responseBody = Enumerable.Empty<T>().ToList();
        }
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), response);
        return response;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Response<T> value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Using it manually would look like this

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<Contact>>(json, new ResponseConverter<Contact>());
```

For the different type of responses, you can create derived classes and apply the converter to that

Like

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ResponseConverter<Contact>))]
public class ContactResponse : Response<Contact> { }

[JsonConverter(typeof(ResponseConverter<Customer>))]
public class CustomerResponse : Response<Customer> { }
```

Comment: I have a question how can we use this `  public class ResponseConverter<T> : JsonConverter<Response<T>> where T : RealmObject` as it throws compile time error `the non-generic type 'JsonConverter' can not be used with type argument`

Comment: are you using `Newtonsoft.Json`?

Comment: Yes. version11.0.2

Comment: i am using the same version , really don't know why i am getting compile time error as `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvertor` is a class that has no generic type involved